# Deploy Sails.js on Openshift ... app restarting over and over

Tags: node.js, openshift, sails.js

I want to deploy **sails.js** (version 0.9.7) app to **Openshift** but after `git push` I get this log:

```
debug: Lowering sails...
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node app.js'
.
.
.
info: Server lifted in `/var/lib/openshift/525ccaba5973caa65100002b/app-root/runtime/repo`
info: To see your app, visit http://127.7.215.1:8080
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.
.
.
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Tue Oct 15 2013 03:03:56 GMT-0400 (EDT)
debug: 
debug: Environment      : development
debug: Host             : 127.7.215.1
debug: Port             : 8080
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
.
.
error: Server doesn't seem to be starting.
error: Perhaps something else is already running on port 8080 with hostname 127.7.215.1?
.
.
debug: Lowering sails...
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node app.js'
```

Following a few tips from [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/929) and also checked the sample `config/local.js` https://gist.github.com/chrisaiv/5938158

After test any of combination the **Openshift** server is just restarting over and over. I have also tested several ports like 8080, 80, 1337, ... and I don't think so are all busy. I've tried to run `node`app.js and application surprisingly works on port 8080 but just till I try access to `views/home/index`, probably because from `ssh` I haven't enought rights.

Just in case, here how my `config/local.js` file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
        port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT,
        host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP
        }
```

thank you for any advice;-)

Comment: I have used openshift before. Its only a hassle...its better not to work on that web/cloud solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your app will keep restarting over and over is because sails application create a folder called `.tmp` and put all assets into it. Which means your sails application will write local files. But **Openshift** use `node-supervisor` to start node application, and `node-supervisor` monitor all file changes after starting the application. If any file is changed, `node-supervisor` will restart the server.

You can try `npm i supervisor -g` and start your application by typing `node-supervisor app.js` to see the same log.

I think the solution is to make SailsJS stop writing local files, but I am not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: Thank you for your info;-) may will help just set the path of .tmp files somewhere to tmp folder which is provide by openshift enviroment. I moved my project to Hapi library which is works fine, but for next project i would like to back to sails which seems like cool staff, thank you one more time;-)