# Deploying Sails.js On Openshift

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, openshift

When I deploy a **Sails.js** app to **OpenShift** it restarts over and over again.

So basically I am having the exact same problem with the same output from `rhc tail` described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375581/deploy-sails-js-on-openshift-app-restarting-over-and-over) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375581/deploy-sails-js-on-openshift-app-restarting-over-and-over/19743428#19743428) describes why this error is occurring but there are no solutions offered

Has anyone successfully deployed a **Sails.js** app to **OpenShift**?

I am committed to the OpenShift platform at this point but really want to use SailsJS for my next app.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to start Sails on OpenShift, you need to set the `port` and `host` config keys in your `/config/local.js` to:

```
port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080,
host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP
```

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375581/deploy-sails-js-on-openshift-app-restarting-over-and-over) / [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375581/deploy-sails-js-on-openshift-app-restarting-over-and-over/19743428#19743428) you referred to is valid; the `supervisor` instance on OpenShift does seem to have a problem with Grunt.  The quick solution is to start your app once to get the `.tmp` directory built, then stop it and move your `Gruntfile.js` elsewhere.  Then you can start your app with `ctl_app start` and it should do fine.  You might also `killall node` before you start the app, just to make sure previous attempts aren't still going.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I had the port part right but not the host. I will give your other suggestions a try also and let you know how they work out.

Comment: @Scott I ask this in the name of @cartoonle: `Isn't local.js for local environment only, how could that change something on OpenShift? Where should i move gruntfile.js to? May i delete it? Rename it?`. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Balder the sails.js documentation says "this is where you include configuration overrides for your local system or for a production deployment." referring to local.js - for Gruntfile.js I just renamed it before deploying and changed it back when developing my application.

Comment: @modernzombie But its included in .gitignore