# Wrong visualization of Sails.js project deployed on Openshift

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, openshift, sails.js, ejs

I deployed my Sails project on Openshift.
It works but I receive errors with websockets and I don't able to load pages built on ejs.

I found these links enough explanatory about grunt/openshift, but I am not able to solve the problem.

[Deploying Sails.js On Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537123/deploying-sails-js-on-openshift)

[Deploy Sails.js on Openshift ... app restarting over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375581/deploy-sails-js-on-openshift-app-restarting-over-and-over)

My nodejs.log is:

```
DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
DEBUG:   program 'app.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node app.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/data/.nodewatch' for changes.
Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
^[[32minfo^[[39m:
^[[32minfo^[[39m:
^[[32minfo^[[39m:    Sails.js           <|
^[[32minfo^[[39m:    v0.9.16             |\
^[[32minfo^[[39m:                       /|.\
^[[32minfo^[[39m:                      / || \
^[[32minfo^[[39m:                    ,'  |'  \
^[[32minfo^[[39m:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
^[[32minfo^[[39m:                 `--'-------'
^[[32minfo^[[39m:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
^[[32minfo^[[39m:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
^[[32minfo^[[39m:
^[[32minfo^[[39m: Server lifted in `/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo`
^[[32minfo^[[39m: To see your app, visit http://127.2.95.129:8080
^[[32minfo^[[39m: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.
^[[34mdebug^[[39m: --------------------------------------------------------
^[[34mdebug^[[39m: :: Wed May 21 2014 14:26:01 GMT-0400 (EDT)
^[[34mdebug^[[39m:
^[[34mdebug^[[39m: Environment  : production
^[[34mdebug^[[39m: Host         : 127.2.95.129
^[[34mdebug^[[39m: Port         : 8080
^[[34mdebug^[[39m: --------------------------------------------------------
^[[31merror^[[39m: Server doesn't seem to be starting.
^[[31merror^[[39m: Perhaps something else is already running on port 8080 with hostname 127.2.95.129?
^[[32minfo^[[39m: handshake authorized qR_aOT3qx40k6X34CF-2
^[[32minfo^[[39m: handshake authorized tnAUouwi-d32h82rCF-3
^[[33mwarn^[[39m: websocket connection invalid
^[[32minfo^[[39m: transport end (undefined)
^[[31merror^[[39m: Error rendering view at :: /var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/views/viewshows/index
^[[31merror^[[39m: Using layout located at :: /var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/views/layout
^[[31merror^[[39m: Error: Failed to lookup view "viewshows/index"
    at Function.app.render (/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:495:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
    at ServerResponse._addResViewMethod.res.view (/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/views/index.js:297:15)
    at module.exports.index (/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/api/controllers/ViewShowsController.js:32:13)
    at _bind.enhancedFn (/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:375:4)
    at callbacks (/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
```

Here my app.js:

```
require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);
```

Here my local.js:

```
module.exports = {
  host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1",
  port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080,
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
}
```

Calling 'env | grep OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT' on openshift console I receive:

```
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT=8080
```

In my opinion the problem isn't the port. The server start and answer correctly.
But when I call a page built on ejs it answer me with a piece of json...

```
{"view":{"name":"viewshows/index","root":"/var/lib/openshift/537b5ae8500446c95900057f/app-root/runtime/repo/views","defaultEngine":"ejs","ext":".ejs"}}
```

...and print the error above in the server log.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to include the relevant changes you made to your app.js or locals that relate to the HOSTNAME and PORT

Comment: Hi, I see that Openshift set the port to 8080. Sometimes I receive the same error "Perhaps something else is already running on port" in my local pc too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that openshift requires your application to listen to a specific port, specified by an environmental variable, not 8080

You're going to want to change your app.js to to use the hostname and port env variables in this [openshift doc](https://www.openshift.com/developers/openshift-environment-variables)